# Cannot convert Group Description to String Variable

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I have the following code:

```
Set objHoldGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & objGroup)
strGroupDesc = (objHoldGroup.Description)
WScript.Echo(strGroupDesc)
```

The variable `strGroupDesc` returns nothing when echoed. I can output the description directly but I need it for further processing. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: Apparently your script sets `Option Explicit` (good), which you didn't tell us about (bad). This option makes defining variables before you can use them mandatory (good). Normally that would raise an "undefined variable" error, though. Since that doesn't seem to happen with your code, you seem to also have an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code (*very* bad), which, again, you chose to keep quiet about (bad).

Next time please don't omit parts of your code that are vital for troubleshooting the problem. And don't use `On Error Resume Next`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue found: I forgot to `Dim strGroupDesc`.